# UEFI with secure boot disabled

Tags: windows-10, uefi

I am using Windows 10 Home x64 and I am getting the following notification:

> UEFI with secure boot is disabled

Is this a default setting or should it be changed?

Can someone explain what it is, as I am not sure what it means?

Comment: [This question and answer](https://superuser.com/questions/493367/what-is-secure-boot-in-windows) on this site describe Secure Boot, but a few of the points are not quite 100% accurate. See [my own page on Secure Boot](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html) for more accurate information, but from a Linux perspective. It's unclear whether you're seeing a firmware message or something displayed by Windows. Also, note that Secure Boot is one optional feature of Secure Boot, but the message implies they're monolithic, which is inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

Secure Boot helps to make sure that your PC boots using only firmware that is trusted by the manufacturer.

After disabling Secure Boot and installing other software and hardware, it may be difficult to re-activate Secure Boot without restoring your PC to the factory state.

Be careful when changing BIOS settings. The BIOS menu is designed for advanced users, and it's possible to change a setting that could prevent your PC from starting correctly. Be sure to follow the manufacturer's instructions exactly.

If you want to re-enable Secure Boot, go to 
Settings charm > Change PC settings > Update and Recovery > Recovery > Advanced Startup: Restart now. When the PC reboots, go to Troubleshoot > Advanced Options: UEFI Firmware Settings.

Find the Secure Boot setting, and if possible, set it to Enabled.

There is a Microsoft article introducing Secure Boot and how to disable/re-enable it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/desktop/disabling-secure-boot

Comment: Secure Boot is to be disabled and enabled without causing a problem your there is no truth to your statement about how there might be a problem.